# Как открыть файл с помощью моей программы на C++

Tags: c++

Я хочу написать мини интерпритатор на с++, для этого я создал файл и задал что бы по умолчанию все такие же файлы открывались в моем exe файле, но что написать в коде что бы он получил расположение данного файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее (как минимум на Windows), пути к файлам должны приходить в параметры командой строки.

Так что:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 2)
        открыть_файл(argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но если вам не трудно, не могли бы вы объяснить зачем там **, и почему тип char - один символ, а на выходе строка?

Comment: @DaniilScrepchenko `char **` - это "указатель на указатель на `char`". Поищите какие-нибудь туториалы по указателям. Говоря грубо, здесь `argv` работает как "массив из массивов символов", т.е. массив строк.